Annotate a constructor that delegates to another function
I have a Python library that encapsulates an external c++ library that exposes its objects via handles. I have a root class
class ABObj:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if is_handle(args[0]):
            self.handle = args[0]
        else:
            self.handle = self._make_obj(*args, **kwargs)

The idea is the constructor can either capture an external handle or create a new object. The latter task is delegated to the subclasses of ABObj.
The problem with this setup is the user gets no parameter hints when instantiating a subclass of ABObj. The autocompletion tool (like Pylance in VS Code) has no idea that the constructor signature is either a single handle or it matches the subclass's _make_obj method. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Look at the @overload decorator

__init__ is doing too much work here. It should accept a handle, period. If the handle needs to be constructed first, that should be done before calling __init__ (perhaps via a dedicated class method). (Is redefining ABObj an option? If so, I can post an answer describing this in more detail.)
